# How can I control a multi-axis arm by giving "target middle link position" instead of the end effector?

Tags: moveit, ros-iron

I am using movegroup_interface with ros2-iron to control a 6-axis arm.

The link structure is as follows.

---

- world
- link1
- link2
- link3
- link4
- link5

  - camera-link
- link6

  - hand-link

---

A camera is attached to the 5th link of this arm and I want to control the position of this camera.
In the attached image, I want to control the position of the camera coordinate system attached to the 5th axis, not the hand coordinate system attached to the 6th axis.

Naturally, I am able to control the hand position of the 6th link as I want, but I am having trouble understanding how to control the position of middle links(1st-5th).

I have specified the link for the 5th axis in the end effector like setEndEffectorLink("camera_link"), but the IK solver fails and it does not work. (Caused by the 6th axis being free?)

Could you please give me some advice?

[image: hand-eye robot arm]

Comment: Have you tried creating a move_group with only the joints you care about, then asking IK to solve for the cartesian goal? (this approach is a guess, I've not tried it myself.)

Comment: Please edit your post to tell us: 1) Is "camera_link" a direct child of a rotating arm joint? If not, I would try using the actual name of the arm link in setEndEffectorLink(), 2) Which IK solver are you using now?, 3) Have you looked at generating a custom Fast IK solver?

Comment: I updated post about arm structure.
I tried move_group consisting of 1 to 5 links, but IK solver failed too.

Comment: 1) Yes. 2) I'm using kdk_kinematics_plugin. 3) Not yet.

Comment: Please edit your post to show us the yaml you used to define the smaller move_group, and format it using the Code Sample button. Another possibility: How much time are you giving the IK solver to find a solution? (The default timeout value is often too short.)

Comment: I solved the problem. Thank you for all the tips.

Answer (score 1):

Create a movegroup for the link up to the intermediate axis, and note that since it is not a 6-axis movegroup, it has less degrees of freedom and does not exactly match the target value.

So, instead of `setJointValueTarget`, use `setApproximateJointValueTarget`.

Comment: The 2nd paragraph does not make sense to me: the MoveGroup.setJointValueTarget() method has nothing to do with IK failing when given a cartesian pose input.

Comment: ... but the idea that you might need to allow a less precise IK solution is reasonable.